# Body with 100% height containting fixed Navbar "Margin Error"

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a sticky responsive navbar in a body with 100% height but whenever I try to check in in mobile screen size the navbar gets marginalized towards the right side.

Also, when I tried the same code in the page containing Bootstrap in it, the padding and margin get imbalanced in the NavBar (Perhaps Bootstrap uses HTML5 ).

Here's my CSS and HTML code. The first one is CSS and the last one is HTML with it's Javascript.

```css
/* Navbar css */
.MainBody {
    padding-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(240, 251, 255), rgb(168, 203, 255));
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 1000px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #020f3b;
  position: fixed;
  /* Safari */
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 11px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #a3dcff;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #0099ff;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 909px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
      display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
      background: rgb(0, 73, 146);
      float: right;
      display: block;
  }

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 909px) {
  .topnav .responsive {
      position: fixed;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
      float: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
  }
}

/* Navbar Css <:: */
```

```html
<body class="MainBody">
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="https://apps.webmatrices.com/adsense-eligibility-checker" class="active">AEC Tool</a>
    <a href="https://webmatrices.com/sponsor-adsense-eligibility-checker/" target='_blank'>Sponsor or Buy AEC</a>
    <a href="https://webmatrices.com/" target='_blank'>Webmatrices</a>
    <a href="https://blog.webmatrices.com/" target='_blank'>Our Blog</a>
    <a href="https://facebook.com/webmatrices" target='_blank'>Facebook Page</a>
    <a href="https://facebook.com/iambishwas" target='_blank'>Creator's Facebook</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
    <!-- Navbar script ::> -->
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        if (x.className === "topnav") {
            x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
            x.className = "topnav";
        }
        }
    </script>
    <!-- Navbar script <:: -->
    <!-- Navbar Bar | nv <:: -->
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening due to comflict of HTML and HTML5(Bootstrap). I got the error bro. I recommend you to use `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` at the top of your html file, this will 100% solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The menu gets set to `display: none` when the screen is below `910px`

Remove this CSS if you don't want the menu to go away on mobile:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 909px)
.topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
}
```